# HTML and javascript not compiling properly

Tags: javascript, html, markup

This code seemed to work properly a few weeks ago.

Now, however, the branching seems entirely broken (browser type of little significance).

Does anybody have any idea why it might no longer be working?

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta name="generator" content="HTML Tidy for Linux (vers 6 November 2007), see www.w3.org" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Examples of Strings</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
         <!-- hide me
         // get a name 
         var monkey = prompt("What's the monkey's name?","The monkey");

// declare some short strings
var demanding = " demands - no - insists upon receiving ";
var requesting = " nicely asks for the benefit of all ";
var tech = " a computer that won't crash, and a homemade browser!";   
var peace = " love for everyone and peace on earth.";
// construct some longer strings
var userRequest = "Do you want to hear what "+ monkey + " wants?"
var techy_monkey = monkey + demanding + tech;
var hippy_monkey = monkey + requesting + peace;
// make some fancy strings
var bold_tech = techy_monkey.bold();
var italic_hippy = hippy_monkey.italics();
var shouting_hippy= hippy_monkey.toUpperCase();
var red_bold_tech = bold_tech.fontcolor('red');
// stop hiding me -->
//]]>
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Monkey Babbles</h1>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
         <!-- hide me


var monkey_love = prompt("Do you love the monkey?","Type yes or no");
if (monkey_love == "yes")
    {
    alert("Welcome! I'm so glad you came! Please, read on!");
    var monkey_statement = prompt(userRequest,"Type yes or no");
        if (monkey_statement == "yes")
        document.writeln(italic_hippy + "<br>");
        break;
    }
    else if  (monkey_love == "no")
    {
    alert("Just giving you the heads up: the monkey hates you too");
    var monkey_statement = prompt("Do you want to hear what the monkey wants?","Type yes or no");
        if (monkey_statement == "yes")
        document.writeln(red_bold_tech + "<br>");
        break;
    }
    else if  (monkey_love == "Type yes or no")
    {
    alert("Do you just randomly click on dialog boxes?");
    var monkey_statement = prompt("Do you want to hear what the monkey wants?","Type yes or no");
        if (monkey_statement == "yes")
        document.writeln(shouting_hippy + "<br>");
        else {
        document.writeln("The monkey is pained by your general lack of interest")
        }
        break;
    }
    else 
    {
    alert("You make no sense to monkey");
    var monkey_statement = prompt("Do you want to hear what the monkey wants?","Type yes or no");
        if (monkey_statement == "yes")
        document.writeln(bold_tech + "<br>");
        break;
    }




// show me -->
//]]>
</script>
<p>
    <a href="http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=referer"><img
        src="http://www.w3.org/Icons/valid-xhtml10"
        alt="Valid XHTML 1.0 Strict" height="31" width="88" /></a>
  </p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: HTML and JavaScript never compile.

Comment: Check your javascript console (shift-ctrl-J in firefox) and look for javascript errors.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot put `break` statements in `if` clauses. If I read your code correctly, you can simply remove them and all should be fine.

Comment: Or "switch" that if else jargon to a switch statement ;-)